# Excel - Datevalue to equal another cell's datevalue, but show up in formulas as that datevalue and not =CELL

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm trying to get two spreadsheets more compatible for ease of copy and pasting.

In my Master spreadsheet, where I'll be pasting everything, all the formulae for dates and times are in DateValue. So when I click on the option to 'show formula', DateValue numbers will show. In normal view, they obviously show the date as DD/MM/YYYY.

In my Working spreadsheet, from which I'll be pasting everything, I need all the values in the same column to be equal to the first date I submit at the top of the column. I have done this by doing = A1 (where I originally put the date) and then dragging down.

The formula view of this spreadsheet now looks like this

```
42034 (So a datevalue) 
=A1
=A2
=A3
=A4
```

(and so on)

I would like it to show

```
42034
42034
42034
42034
42034
```

Obviously without having to type the same datevalue every time in the 'view formulas' view.

This makes it easier to copy and paste consistently between other spreadsheets amongst a large team without as many copy and paste mistakes.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem? You want it to show the DateValue of like 402034 instead of 11/2015?  Or the cell is showing literally `=A1` instead of what's actually *in* `A1`?

Comment: When I go into the 'view formulae' view I want it to show the DateValue and not =A1

In normal view, I want it to show the date

Comment: AFAIK you won't be able to show the date, in the Formula View mode. Since the formula is `=A1`, that'll show.  Why not just format those cells as General?  But is your main question about Copy/Paste? Can you explain a little more what the big picture is, so we can try and avoid an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Why would you use "view formulas" if you don't actually want to view them?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than enter `=A1` and drag down, just `Copy` (A1) >`Paste` (needed cells)  the date from the first cell (or, after having formulas entered do `Copy` (column) > `Paste Values`)